# How can I read a string with spaces in it in C?

Tags: c, string, spaces

scanf("%s",str) won't do it. It will stop reading at the first space. 
gets(str) doesn't work either when the string is large. Any ideas?

Comment: `gets` never works. It's an inherent bug to ever use `gets`. Use `fgets`.

Comment: Maybe it's my version of c that won't accept gets at all...Thanks!

Comment: @Johnny: R's admonition against using `gets()` is due to the fact that using it introduces a *huge* security hole in your code, not that your particular compiler has an issue with it (it shouldn't; `gets()` has been part of the C since the beginning).  It's been deprecated as of C99 and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use [fgets](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) with STDIN as the file stream.  Then you can specify the amount of data you want to read and where to put it.

Comment: fgets(str1, 100, stdin); fgets(str2, 100, stdin); I won't get asked for the first string. It goes directly to the second one. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment means - is something not working?

Comment: I won't get prompted to insert the first string.

Comment: we don't have enough information to help you with these other issues you have.  `fgets` is a blocking read, so you would do something like `printf("enter line here\n");` then call `fgets(...)` - fgets should not return until the user enters something with a newline

Comment: That's what I did, but when I run the program, the error window appears before I enter anything... Anyway thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
char str[100];
```

Try this

```
 scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
```

or this

```
fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
```

Comment: 1) There is not reason for `s` in `"%[^\n]s"`.  2) `scanf("%[^\n]...` will scan nothing and save nothing in `str` if input is `"\n"`. 3) `scanf("%[^\n]...` does not protect against large input. 4) `scanf("%[^\n]...` leaves `'\n'` in `stdin`.

Comment: Also the `s` does not make sense here. `%[^\n]` already asks for all characters but a new-line.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own function to read a line. Here's what you basically have to do:

```
1. fgets into allocated (growable) memory
2. if it was a full line you're done
3. grow the array
4. fgets more characters into the newly allocated memory
5. goto 2.
```

The implementation may be a bit tricky :-)

You need to think about what you need to pass to your function (at the very least the address of the array and its size); and what the function returns when everything "works" or when there is an error. You need to decide what is an error (is a string 10Gbytes long with no '\n' an error?). You need to decide on how to grow the array.

---

Edit

Actually it may be better to `fgetc` rather than `fgets`

```
get a character
it it EOF? DONE
add to array (update length), possible growing it (update size)
is it '\n'? DONE
repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

When do you want to stop reading? At EOF, at a specific character, or what?

You can read a specific number of characters with %c

> c     Matches a sequence of width
>   count characters (default 1); the next
>              pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room
>              for all the characters (no terminating NUL is added).  The usual
>              skip of leading white space is suppressed.  To skip white space
>              first, use an explicit space in the format.

You can read specific characters (or up to excluded ones) with %[

> [     Matches a nonempty sequence of
>   characters from the specified set of
>              accepted characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to
>   char,
>              and there must be enough room for all the characters in the
>   string,
>              plus a terminating NUL character.  The usual skip of leading
>   white
>              space is suppressed.  The string is to be made up of characters
>   in
>              (or not in) a particular set; the set is defined by the
>   characters
>              between the open bracket [ character and a close bracket ]
>   charac-
>              ter.  The set excludes those characters if the first
>   character
>              after the open bracket is a circumflex ^.  To include a close
>              bracket in the set, make it the first character after the open
>              bracket or the circumflex; any other position will end the set.
>              The hyphen character - is also special; when placed between two
>              other characters, it adds all intervening characters to the set.
>              To include a hyphen, make it the last character before the final
>              close bracket.  For instance, `[^]0-9-]' means the set
>   ``everything
>              except close bracket, zero through nine, and hyphen''.  The
>   string
>              ends with the appearance of a character not in the (or, with a
>   cir-
>              cumflex, in) set or when the field width runs out

Comment: I just don't want blanks in between the string. I tried scanf("%[^\n]",str); but didn't work either. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I guess but that means up to 79 chars, right? I need a string that may be larger.

Comment: A line to me means all characters upto a new line. Can you describe in more detail what you actually want to do here?

Comment: Ok. I want to do: 


char* str1;


printf("Give a string\n"); 
scanf("%s",str1);

char str2[strlen(str1)];

for(int i=0; i<strlen(str1); i++)
 str2[i] = str1[i];


Is this somehow helpful?

Comment: @Johny try scanf("%[^\n]s",str); you have missed 's' in the scanf().

Answer (score 1):

To read string with space you can do as follows:

```
char name[30],ch;

i=1;
while((ch=getchar())!='\n')
{
name[i]=ch;
i++;
}
i++;
name[i]='\n';
printf("String is %s",name);
```

Comment: `ch` should be `int` to distinguish `EOF` from all other `char`.  As it is now, `while((ch=getchar())!='\n')` is an infinite loop should `EOF` be return from `getchar()`.