# Read a string with whitespace

Tags: c, string, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

 int n;

 scanf("%d",&n);

  char str[500];

 scanf("%[^\n]s",str);

  printf("%d\n",n);

  printf("%s",str);

return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
5 7 1 2 3
```

Output:

```
5 5 ->
```

I want the output to be

```
5

7 1 2 3
```

Can anybody help me with my code... Please

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read a string with spaces in it in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025673/how-can-i-read-a-string-with-spaces-in-it-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Use [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) to read the line:

```
 fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
```

Later parse the line `str`, perhaps using [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) (possibly with `%n`)  or [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
```

to read till end of line.

Then in order to get the integers you can use `strtok()` to break the line into tokens and convert tokens to intgers using `strtol()`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use scanf() and read a number before starting getting the input, you could do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int numbers[128];
  int n;

  printf("How many numbers to read?\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
How many numbers to read?
5
1 2 3 4 5
1
2
3
4
5
```

---

Use [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). Feed the function with `stdin`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char line[256];
  char* pch;
  int numbers[128];
  int N = 0; // actual numbers of numbers read

  // to read one line
  fgets(line, 256, stdin);
  line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
  pch = strtok(line, " ");
  while (pch != NULL) {
    numbers[N++] = atoi(pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }

  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Why OP code fails: With user input like <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>   <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The first `scanf()` consumes `"5"`, leaving `"\na b\n"` for the next `scanf()`.  That `scanf()` scans nothing and saves nothing into `str` as the first `char` is a `'\n'`.

```
scanf("%d",&n);
scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
```

---

For reading a line `scanf("%[^\n]s",str);` has a number of problems.

1. There is not reason for the `s` in  `"%[^\n]s"`
2. `"%[^\n]"` will not save anything into `str` if input is `"\n"`.
3. No protection against reading too much data.
4. Code should check the return value from `scanf()`.

As suggested by many, use `fgets()`

```
  char str[500];
  if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL) HandleEOForIOerror();

  // to remove '\n'
  size_t len = strlen(str);
  if (len > 0 && str[len-1] == '\n') str[--len] = 0;

  printf("%s",str);
```

---

To read the number, recommend the same, use `fgets()`

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int n;
  char str[500];
  if (fgets( str, sizeof str, stdin) return -1;
  if (1 == sscanf(str, "%d",&n)) {
    printf("%d\n",n);
  }
  if (fgets( str, sizeof str, stdin) return -1;
  printf("%s",str);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d",&n);` change to `scanf("%d%*c", &n);`
or
`scanf("%[^\n]s", str);` change to `scanf(" %[^\n]", str);`

Comment: embarrassing X), it is typo.