# C scanf() does not read full line

Tags: c, scanf

I want to create text cleaner for homework, but when I start programs with address sanitiser I have `heap-buffer-overflow` exception even if I use `free()`.

expected output:

```
he3llo world
helloworld
```

real output:

```
he3llo world
hello
```

Thanks in advance for any answer!

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char* fix_text(char* data, int len)
{
    char* fixed_message = malloc (len * sizeof(char));
    int offset = 0; //used for correct parse
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        
        if (isalpha(data[i]))
        {
            
            fixed_message[offset] = data[i];
            offset++; 
        }
        
        else if(data[i] == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(data[i] == ' ')
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return fixed_message;
}
int main()
{
    char * text = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", text);
    char* result = fix_text(text, 100);
    printf("%s\n", result);
    free(text);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should end your string with \0, as it is now you only break but do not end the string properly.

Also the third case with continue is not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with the code outputting just `hello` is not associated with the cycle stopping. It is because your `scanf` is only reading until the space. So the string `text` you are passing to your function is basically only `hello`.
You can fix that by using

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",text);
```

to read until the new line. For more details you can see
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025673/how-can-i-read-a-string-with-spaces-in-it-in-c)

Also as @Jabberwocky has pointed out, you are not terminating your fixed message. You can just add the null terminator `\0` at the end of your fixed message when you're encountering the same in your original message instead of just breaking

```
else if(data[i] == '\0')
{
    fixed_message[offset] = data[i];
    break;
}
```